# How to compare json response with mysql query in JAVA

Tags: java, json

I am trying to comparing Json response with my sql query result.

Json Response:

```
[
  {
    "id": "1023313",
    "empno": "073130425890",
    "empForma": "0",
    "status": "success",
    "message": ""
  },
  {
    "id": "43781661",
    "empno": "073130425890",
    "empForma": "0",
    "status": "success",
    "message": ""
  },
  {
    "id": "63535011",
    "empno": "000004501951",
    "empForma": "2",
    "status": "success",
    "message": ""
  },
  {
    "id": "184570",
    "status": "success",
    "message": "No Data Available"
  }
]
```

I have stored SQL Query Output in string:
queryResult:

```
[1023313 073130425890 0, 43781661 073130425890 0, 63535011 000004501951 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

Comparing strings will be difficult and error prone.

Better parse both your json and query result to POJOs and use equals method to compare them.